# Cannot Drag and Drop Anything on to the design (even with a context_main.xml file)

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio 2.3.3, but cannot Drag and Drop anything on to the design blueprint even with a `context_main.xml` file, which a number of solutions indicate, nor do I have `"Drag-n-Drop with ALT pressed only"` selected.

Have also tried reducing the default "Hello World" text view to `5dp` just in case it was stopping me from overlaying a button on a textview that was taking up the whole screen area.

Print screen below. Any help would be grateful.

[image: Print Screen]

Comment: You shouldn't use drag and drop to design your interface. Otherwise you'll have a lot a screen size compatibility issues.

Comment: Hi @TheodoreM,
Thanks for the reply, 
I'm just starting Android coding, so find it helps a little with the auto generation of the code of the components.
This might be an issue with the install of Android studio on Windows 10, as it work on my Windows 7 laptop.
I'm on a bit of a tight deadline for an assignment, so need all the help I can get though Android Studio, to at least develop the proof of concept prototype and demo learning of certain Android programming concepts, I can then later come back to it, develop a more rounded programming style and better developed app.
Thanks again

Comment: I don't know why it isn't working. But if you don't solve your problem you can try [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) to implement your layout. I think RelativeLayout is the most flexible root layout to implement a rough layout easily